# Display data on conditional basis

Tags: javascript, angular

i have a structure where i need to show the data on the basis of some conditions like :

suppose i have 
EmployeeId, EmployeeName, CompanyName and ... as keys. if i select employeeName then all the EmployeeName will get listed in to table, then if i select EmployeeId it should list the EmployeeId in relation to EmployeeName .. like :

[image]
It is like i am trying to get the functionality like pivot table of excel

I have tried by getting the data from jsonfile and then storing it and creating the json object but problem with it is that i am not getting the corresponding relational data..

```
createJSON(e:any,attributeData) {
    this.count++;
    this.jsonObj = [];
    for(var i = 0; i < this.pivotItems.length; i++) {
        var item = {};
        for(var j = 0; j < attributeData.length; j++) {
            item [attributeData[j]] = [this.pivotItems[i][attributeData[j]]];
            if( this.jsonObj.indexOf(item) == -1) {
                this.jsonObj.push(item);
            }
        }
    }
    // item [e.dragData] = e.dragData;
    //this.jsonObj.push(item);
    //this.relatedData();
    console.log(this.jsonObj);
}
```

Comment: Can you provide a functional jsbin example and the expected output?

Comment: Why do you need pivot here?